# How do I know if my ansible role script worked? I am trying to install Azure Modules

Tags: azure, powershell, ansible

I have the following role added to the playbook I am running:

```
- name: Install Az Modules
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      Install-Module Az -force -confirm:$false -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Repository "PSGallery"

- name: Import Az Modules
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      Import-Module Az
```

The output I get for the first part is:

```
changed: [<agent>] => {
    "changed": true,
    "debug": [],
    "error": [],
    "host_err": "",
    "host_out": "",
    "information": [],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "arguments": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "depth": 2,
            "error_action": "continue",
            "executable": null,
            "parameters": null,
            "removes": null,
            "script": "Install-Module Az -force -confirm:$false -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Repository \"PSGallery\" \n"
        }
    },
    "output": [],
    "result": {},
    "verbose": [],
    "warning": []
}
```

This is the only output I get from ansible...how do I know if the install command worked properly? The text is yellow so I feel like it didn't work properly.

When I run my TC build the module doesn't exist:

```
[08:14:25][Step 1/2] Connect-AzAccount : The term 'Connect-AzAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
[08:14:25][Step 1/2] operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
[08:14:25][Step 1/2] again.
```

When I run this command on my :

```
Get-InstalledModule
```

in my TC build logs it shows:

```
[08:14:24][Step 1/2] Version    Name                                Repository           Description                                        
[08:14:24][Step 1/2] -------    ----                                ----------           -----------                                        
[08:14:24][Step 1/2] 1.0.2.201  newtonsoft.json                     PSGallery            Serialize/Deserialize Json using Newtonsoft.json   
[08:14:24][Step 1/2] 0.6.11     Octoposh                            PSGallery            This module contains a set of cmdlets that talk ...
```

So I do not think the modules are being installed.  I do not know how to get ansible to show more output.

I am using the following command to run my playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts Configure_sdlc2_playbook.yml --tag azure_cli -vvv
```

Comment: 1) `script` module should only be used to install prereqs to use ansible on the target. In this particular case, you have plenty of [dedicated azure modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/index.html) to do the job 2) The only output you can capture on ansible side is the one provided by your script which means it should output the needed info and exit with the proper code in case of failure so that ansible knows there was a problem. Since we have no idea of what your script looks like, there is no way to give any answer at this stage.

Comment: Which dedicated azure module should I use to install Az.Accounts?  Or download all the modules? I don't see it there.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by changing the -scope to AllUsers.  It was installing them on a different user than the one my TCAgent was using.